# pset4 filter edges function fails check50 completely

Tags: c, cs50

So I've finished my edges function and I can't wrap my head around why it fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The edges function is supposed to detect edges in a bitmap.
Here is my edges function:

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Copy of image so that we calculate based on the original values of RGB
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Stores RGB values of each pixel in grid
    RGBTRIPLE grid[3][3];
    // Iterate over every pixel and alter its RGB values
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            reset(grid);
            // Includes current pixel in center of 3 x 3 grid
            grid[1][1] = copy[i][j];
            // Checks if left edge exists and if so, assigns to left edge in 3 x 3 grid
            if (j != 0)
            {
                grid[1][0] = copy[i][j - 1];
            }
            // Checks if right edge exists
            if (j + 1 != width)
            {
                grid[1][2] = copy[i][j + 1];
            }
            // Checks if top edge exists
            if (i != 0)
            {
                grid[0][1] = copy[i - 1][j];
            }
            // Checks if bottom edge exists
            if (i + 1 != height)
            {
                grid[2][1] = copy[i + 1][j];
            }
            // Checks if top left corner exists
            if (i != 0 && j != 0)
            {
                grid[0][0] = copy[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
            // Checks if top right corner exists
            if (i != 0 && j + 1 != width)
            {
                grid[0][2] = copy[i - 1][j + 1];
            }
            // Checks if bottom left corner exists
            if (i + 1 != height && j != 0)
            {
                grid[2][0] = copy[i + 1][j - 1];
            }
            // Checks if bottom right corner exists
            if (i + 1 != height && j + 1 != width)
            {
                grid[2][2] = copy[i + 1][j + 1];
            }
            // Store products of x version and y version
            RGBTRIPLE XX[3][3], YY[3][3];
            duplicate(grid, XX);
            duplicate(grid, YY);
            // Multiplies each pixel in grid by corresponding values for x version
            multiply(&XX[0][0], -1);
            multiply(&XX[2][0], -1);
            multiply(&XX[1][0], -2);
            multiply(&XX[1][2], 2);
            multiply(&XX[0][2], 1);
            multiply(&XX[2][0], 1);
            multiply(&XX[0][1], 0);
            multiply(&XX[1][1], 0);
            multiply(&XX[2][1], 0);
            // Multiplies each pixel in grid by corresponding values for y version
            multiply(&YY[0][0], -1);
            multiply(&YY[0][2], -1);
            multiply(&YY[0][1], -2);
            multiply(&YY[2][1], 2);
            multiply(&YY[2][0], 1);
            multiply(&YY[2][2], 1);
            multiply(&YY[1][0], 0);
            multiply(&YY[1][1], 0);
            multiply(&YY[1][2], 0);
            // Stores sum of the products for x and y version
            RGBTRIPLE Gx, Gy;
            Gx.rgbtRed = Gx.rgbtGreen = Gx.rgbtBlue = Gy.rgbtRed = Gy.rgbtGreen = Gy.rgbtBlue = 0;
            sum(&Gx, XX);
            sum(&Gy, YY);
            set_pixel(Gx, Gy, &image[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the functions that support edges:

```
// Sets new RGB values for a pixel
void set_pixel(RGBTRIPLE Gx, RGBTRIPLE Gy, RGBTRIPLE *pixel)
{
    int red, green, blue;
    red = (int) round(sqrt((Gx.rgbtRed * Gx.rgbtRed) + (Gy.rgbtRed * Gy.rgbtRed)));
    green = (int) round(sqrt((Gx.rgbtGreen * Gx.rgbtGreen) + (Gy.rgbtGreen * Gy.rgbtGreen)));
    blue = (int) round(sqrt((Gx.rgbtBlue * Gx.rgbtBlue) + (Gy.rgbtBlue * Gy.rgbtBlue)));
    if (red > 255)
    {
        red = 255;
    }
    if (green > 255)
    {
        green = 255;
    }
    if (blue > 255)
    {
        blue = 255;
    }
    pixel->rgbtRed = red;
    pixel->rgbtGreen = green;
    pixel->rgbtBlue = blue;
}

// Adds the products for each colour together
void sum(RGBTRIPLE *sum, RGBTRIPLE g[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            sum->rgbtRed += g[i][j].rgbtRed;
            sum->rgbtGreen += g[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            sum->rgbtBlue += g[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
}

// Copies 3 x 3 grid into XX or YY
void duplicate(RGBTRIPLE grid[3][3], RGBTRIPLE c[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            c[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
// Resets 3 x 3 grid all to 0
void reset(RGBTRIPLE grid[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            grid[i][j].rgbtRed = grid[i][j].rgbtGreen = grid[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Multiplies the amount of each colour by a given factor
void multiply(RGBTRIPLE *x, int factor)
{
    x->rgbtRed *= factor;
    x->rgbtGreen *= factor;
    x->rgbtBlue *= factor;
}
```

For more info, here's what check50 says:
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/081a89d81042ad121b7f63d2af8deaf8225cca71

Comment: Sure about `sum->rgbtRed += g[i][j].rgbtRed;`  I'd expect `sum->rgbtRed` to readily overflow.

Comment: The sum of the rbg components of the 8 neighbours will overflow the maximum value `255` which can be held. Sum the neighbours' components to three separate `int` variables.

Comment: Aside: Could replace `for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) { for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
 copy[i][j] = image[i][j]; } }` with `memcpy(copy, image, sizeof copy)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I completely forgot about the maximum values. Turns out that the multiply function also has the same issue. I appreciate the help.